# custom slide animation of snackbar

Tags: android, snackbar

I made a snackbar on the top of my layout. BUT, when it appears, it slides upwards and when it is dismissed, it slides downwards. My wish is to make it appear from the top of the screen and slides down, and vice-versa.

```
CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout = findViewById(R.id.v_set_bgs);
snackbar = Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, R.string.changes, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
View view = snackbar.getView();
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
params.gravity = Gravity.START;
TextView snackbarText = view.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
snackbarText.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
view.setLayoutParams(params);
view.setAlpha(0.75f);
if (snackbarShow && isAlready == 0 && AppSettings.isChanged) {
    isAlready = 1;
    snackbar.show();
}
```

So. So far, it's working like a normal snackbar (on the top of the layout). I just couldn't find any method how to change the slide direction.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation

> Snackbars provide lightweight feedback about an operation. They show a
>   brief message at the bottom of the screen on mobile and lower left on
>   larger devices. Snackbars appear above all other elements on screen
>   and only one can be displayed at a time.

The best option you can do is extend `Snackbar` class and override the `show` method or another whatever is responsible for the animation

Comment: Thanks for answer. Do you know if I can change the animation to fade in and out?

Comment: @MihaiComan How about placing a custom view and use the ViewCompat.animate to animate the view according to the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

This makes the Snackbar appears on Top without the strange slide in transition.

Best simple solution in Kotlin:

```
val snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, string, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
val layoutParams = LayoutParams(snackbar.view.layoutParams)

layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP
snackbar.view.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 0)
snackbar.view.layoutParams = layoutParams
snackbar.animationMode = BaseTransientBottomBar.ANIMATION_MODE_FADE
snackbar.show()
```

Comment: It's not same animation with ANIMATION_MODE_SLIDE, it makes fade in/out animation

Comment: @faskN Mihai asked for this solution in Rahul's answer.

Comment: Sorry, i thought this is the answer of Rahul's question.